# How to manage the private key of the provisioning template in AWS IoT Fleet provisioning on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, private-key, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am planning to connect many android devices to my AWS IoT Core via fleet provisioning.
The process consists in creating a provisioning claim certificate in AWS, which provides the certificate and an associated private key to download.
Then the devices may request their own private key and certificate using the claim certificate and its associated private key.

However, it is not secured and thus not allowed to build an apk with the claim certificate associated private key hard-coded.

How should I handle the claim certificate associated private key in this context ? Or should I use another process ?